# How to track the disappearance of an object (TV logo) from the ROI (logo rect on a frame)?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing

I have a TV logo image and a rect where the logo is placed on almost all video frames. But there are also frames where the logo completely disappears (at least 10 consecutive seconds of running frames). TV logo is placed only in only one place (ROI = full logo rect) throughout the video, so I don't need to analyze full frame. I tried `matchTemplate` in ROI using **OpenCV**, it works, but I don't think this way is good enough. How can I track when there is no logo in this area (ROI) with OpenCV with the exception of template matching?

Comment: Train an object detector on that Logo. You could try [HOG](http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html) or to archieve even better detection accuracy [MMOD](http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_ex.cpp.html) (Links to examples of the dlib machine learning library given).

Comment: Also I think I can check if two images (TV logo and cropped from the frame with logo rect) are almost similar. But I don't know how to do this :S

Comment: Can you also provide the logo ? Because if it is very particular you could try some more rudimentar algorithms

Comment: There is no specific logo. It can be any channel. At first I generated a time averaged frame from grayscale frames. So every region became more and more gray over time except the TV logo (which is stable throughout the video). Afterward I applied edge detection to identify the region of a logo. That's how I get the TV logo. I don't have any TV logos before running the program:) I'm just defining the area of a logo.